# date of max and min bar on the label

Tags: pine-script

How can I write a code to find the maximum and minimum bar on the entire chart, then create a label and display the date of the maximum and minimum in it?
I tried to do it in different ways, but unfortunately I didn't save all attempts of my code.

Comment: Then perhaps you can show us your last attempt?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `var` declared variable to store either `time` or time-related variables. if you are talking about getting the date and time of highest high and lowest low, try something like this:

```
var float my_high = high
var float my_low = low
var int high_time = na
var int low_time = na
if high > my_high
    my_high := high
    high_time := time
...
```

Then use time functions like `hour()`, `dayofmonth()` on the stored time variables. Combine with `tostring()` to generate a text string to put in the label. Here's an example, https://www.tradingview.com/script/xSOjex8K-Chart-Date-Range/ which I made to answer this question, then realized that you were probably asking for the highest high and lowest low rather than the date range. Regardless the technique is just as I described, the only difference being I stored the individual time variables (`hour`, `dayofmonth`, `year`, etc.) instead of using the time functions on a stored time.

Comment: thanks for your help, well, I solved this problem with this method

`//here I found the maximum

src = high
var float high_bar = src
var float ath_price_time = na

if src > high_bar
    high_bar := src
    ath_price_time := time


    
//I found the minimum    
i_src = low
var float low_bar = i_src
var float low_price_time = na
if i_src < low_bar
    low_bar := i_src
    low_price_time := time

ath = high_bar
min = low_bar


//I created a label and entered the date into it
str.format(" {0,date,full}", ath_price_time)
str.format(" {0,date,full}", low_price_time)`